# Ubuntu SDK: Provide your application identifier in $APP_ID environment variable

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm getting familiar with Ubuntu SDK and QML.

After creating sample project: 'App with Simple UI', I'm able to run it correctly.

But, I'm getting warning:

```
unity::action::ActionManager::ActionManager(QObject*):
Could not determine application identifier. HUD will not work properly.
Provide your application identifier in $APP_ID environment variable.

** (qmlscene:16973): WARNING **: Unable to register app: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid application ID
```

**How to provide such id per application? Should I put it somewhere in code?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably getting this warning because you're developing your application on a desktop.

QML applications using Ubuntu components need this for identifying themselves throughout the system, see [ApplicationId](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppStore/Interfaces/ApplicationId).

To get rid of this warning, just prefix your `qmlscene` command like this:

```
   APP_ID=foo qmlscene ./foo.qml
```

Resources:

- [Ubuntu.Components.MainView](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.MainView/#applicationName-prop)
- [ApplicationConfinement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/ApplicationConfinement#Launching_applications)

Comment: Thanks. Is QML meant for developing apps for desktop?

Comment: Of course you can develop apps for desktop. QML is really powerful to create UI. The app_id was just a warning, nothing to worry about. I put some links in the qml tag (see http://askubuntu.com/tags/qml/info)